# How does the email template vars works within Magento?

Tags: php, email, templates, magento

I needed to create a specific email template sent using an observer running from a cron.
When I received the email, I don't have the value of the provided variables.

```
$vars = array(
    'product'  => $product,
    'customer' => $customer
);

$mailTemplate->sendTransactional(
    $mailId,
    'general',
    $customer->getData('email'),
    $customer->getData('firstname') . ' ' . $customer->getData('lastname'),
    $vars
);
```

`$product` & `$customer` are both object from a Model Collection (Product_Collection & Customer_Collection).

In my template, I'm trying to access them like this:

```
Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},
<p>Check {{htmlescape var=$product.name}}</p>
```

Any ideas?

By the way, how can I construct url to my product? (to let the customer click on a link to view the product)

Comment: clap your hands and start to debug if your variables are in place when the actual filter is applied. Best thing to use is http://www.xdebug.org/ and used together with your php ide you can start a debugging session

Answer (score 4):

Try it without the dollar signs on your variables. Looking at the default email templates, they do not appear to contains those dollar symbols.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

These parameters are tokenized while the part before the `.` is considered the object and string after is the `method` to be called on that object.

So `$customer.name` is evaluated to `$customer->name()` during template processing. To retrieve the customer's name you would call `$customer->getName()` in PHP, therefore use `$customer.getName()` in the template.

*But* there is an important difference in how the parameters should be passed for different template methods. As I can gather from the source code, all template methods taking the parameters as a single argument without an attribute assignment should be called without the leading `$` while all methods using an attribute require the `$` as prefix.

Attribute assignment

```
{{htmlescape var=$customer.getName()}}
```

But as a single param

```
{{var customer.getName()}}
```

Find all available methods in the class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` by looking at the `*Directive()` functions.